# Sorting superscript numbers

Tags: original-vim, sort

I have the following text in a buffer:

```
² b
³ c
¹ a
⁰ 
⁴ d
```

The issue is that this is the text after running :sort (and :sort n ).  My question is: why doesn't the superscripted numbers sort in the expected order, and how can I make them do so?

EDIT:

:%sort l failed for me as shown:

[image]

Comment: What does just `:language` show you? Before/after the `:language collate en_US.UTF-8` command... Does it mention `LC_ALL`? If so, perhaps that's the problem... Also check the `locale -a` command in your shell, to see which locales are supported, is `en_US.utf8` in the list at all? Maybe you don't have it installed? Are you on a Linux platform, if so, which distribution?

Answer (score 6):

You can sort these symbols properly by using collation locale sort (modifier l):

```
:%sort l
```

For this to work, you need to have language collate setting set properly, for example:

```
:language collate en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't get this to work on a vim --clean (or indeed, any vim) - I've added a fuller response and screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Because the superscript numbers are *not* numbers. They are symbols. Let's assume you are using unicode, then the symbols are represented by the hexadecimal codes 0x00b2, 0x00b3, 0x00b9, 0x8304, 0x8308. And this also explains the sorted order - `:sort` will sort by the number representation of the symbols.